# Colour ID is being fetched from productcolours table but how to get colour name from colours table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
$product = Products::where('product_slug', $slug)->first();
$productcolours = Productcolour::all()->where('product_id', $product->id);
$colour = Colour::all();
```

product.blade

```
@foreach($productcolours as $productcolour)
{{$productcolour->color_id}}
@endforeach
```

Fetch colour name

Comment: Please can you show your table definitions/migrations for these tables.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what your data looks like, but it looks like you would want to build an array of colors from your `Colour::all();` query and reference it by key  (`color_id`) inside your loop

Comment: I think your product and colour's relationship is many-to-many, the productcolour is the pivot table?

Comment: Could you plz add your models ?

Comment: Did either of the below answers solve you problem or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up a [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between `Products` and `Colour` e.g. add the following to your `Products` model (if it doesn't already exists):

```
public function colors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class);
}
```

Without seeing your table definitions I wouldn't be able to say for certain that the above code will work as is. It is currently assuming that you've followed Laravel's standard naming convention.

Then you should simply be able to load the relationship:

```
$product = Products::with('colors')->where('product_slug', $slug)->first();
```

```
@foreach($product->colors as $color)
    {{ $color->name }}
@endforeach
```

---

Just an FYI, in the future I would recommend filtering using the database rather than retrieving **all** of the records and then filtering them down i.e.

this:

```
$productcolours = Productcolour::all()->where('product_id', $product->id);
```

would become:

```
$productcolours = Productcolour::where('product_id', $product->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your product model

```
public function color()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Productcolour', 'id', 'color_id');
}
```

Above code will work when your product table `color_id` match with color table `id`

to show in front end use below code(1 is a product id, use your dynamic id `$product->id`)

```
{{Products::find(1)->color}}
```

or
in controller `$colour = Products::find(1)->color;`